# How to build generic type parameter

Tags: generics, parameters, lambda, types, expression-trees

I have a question.
How can I build a generic type parameter?
I am trying to build an expression tree and I have the following line to build:

```
var expression = Expression
                .Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                    operation,
                    new ParameterExpression[] {parameter});
```

So it is expected that I specify type parameter for T in .Lambda> but the type parameter T in not known until runtime.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could write it in a generic method:

```
public Expression<Func<T,bool>> BuildExpression<T>(...)
{
    // Whatever you need to do
    var expression = Expression
            .Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                operation,
                new ParameterExpression[] {parameter});
}
```

... and then call that method via reflection. Alternatively:

- You could call the generic `Expression.Lambda` method via reflection
- You could call [the non-generic overload of `Expression.Lambda`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268052.aspx)

Without knowing anything more about your requirements, it's very hard to give any advice about which of these would be the most suitable approach. Please edit your question to give more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I am trying to build is a utility that will convert a query made in the user interface, to query in domain. The problem is that the UI sees only DTO classes not the domain, so I must convert linq expression (personDTO x) => x.Name into (Person x)=>x.Name. Somehow I've managed to parse and build the expression. now what remains is the final step. Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>. The problem is that I don't know the parameter T - (this is the type parameter of the real domain object ie. (Person)) because this type parameter is build in runtime.

Comment: @Luka: Well, that's given *some* more information - and I suspect that the final option is the one that is most suitable here.